# problem in looping and passing data in vue component

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

guys its my first time to ask a question here in stackoverflow and i really needs an answer

i have a project which i get data from external api from pinia (similar to VueX) then i pass them into a page then i loop through the data and purse them into a component card to be a dynamic component which renders what ever the data i get

i am having a problem in passing the data into the dynamic component.
i fetched the data successflly in pinia , store it into the state in the store . but cant make it into a variable to loop through them

first iam using typescript

for shop interface `ShopData.ts`

```
export default interface ShopData {
  id: string
  name: string
  logoPath: string
  address: string
}
```

for `types.ts`

```
export type Shop = ShopData
```

that is my `ShopQueries.ts`

```
import { acceptHMRUpdate, defineStore } from 'pinia'
import type { Shop } from '~/types'
import { getShops } from '~/api/ShopsQueries'

export const useShopQueriesStore = defineStore('ShopQueries', {
  state: () => ({
    shops: [] as Shop[],
  }),
  actions: {
    async getShops(num: number) {
      const response = await getShops(num)

      this.shops = response.data

      return this.shops
    },
  },
})

if (import.meta.hot)
  import.meta.hot.accept(acceptHMRUpdate(useShopQueriesStore, import.meta.hot))
```

the page file `index.vue`

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { useShopQueriesStore } from '~/stores/ShopQueries'
import type { Shop } from '~/types'

const shopStore = useShopQueriesStore()

const shops = ref<Shop[] | null>()

onMounted(async() => {
  shops.value = await shopStore.getShops(6)
})
</script>
<template>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-xxl-4 mt-3 my-3">
      <ShopCard
        v-for="shop in shopStore.$state.shops"
        :key="shop.id"
        :address="shop.address"
        :name="shop.name"
        :image="shop.logoPath"
      />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Which i also want to make it a card and wraps down and i cant :(

that is the card component `ShopCard.vue`

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import type { PropType } from '@vue/runtime-core'
import type { Shop } from '~/types'

const props = defineProps({
  shop: null as null | PropType<Shop>,

})
console.log(props)

onMounted(() => {

})

const { shop } = toRefs(props)

</script>

<template>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-body d-flex flex-center flex-column pt-12 p-9">
      <div class="symbol symbol-65px symbol-circle mb-5">
        <img src="{{shop.image}}" alt="image">
      </div>
      <a class="fs-4 text-gray-800 text-hover-primary fw-bolder mb-0" href="">{{ shop.name }}</a>
    </div>
    <div class="fw-bold text-gray-400 mb-6">
      {{ shop.address }}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

i know its hard .. but i really needs some help please !
the whole task depends on it
waiting for help ...

Comment: Some one help me please

Comment: Did you solve the problem?